# idHTTP Post raise exception cannot open file

Tags: delphi, indy10, idhttp

When I call `idHTTP.Post( cUrlPath + '/user/logout.json','')` to logout from a WebService, I always get an exception:

> cannot open file ""

All other `idHTTP.Post` requests work good (log in, create, etc).

I have added a `try-except` block to manage this issue, but I would like to know why it happens, and what I can do to avoid it.

Comment: Use the debugger and break at the code which raises the exception.

Comment: Thanks very much. That's the problem. As you has written down, I was calling idhttp.post with an empty string. I've made a mistake when posting my question. I'm sorry. If you want, add your comment as an answer and I'll check it as the right answer.

Comment: @briast answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have shown is calling `Post()` with only a URL and no data to send to the server. There is NO overloaded version of `Post()` that accepts only 1 parameter as input, ALL OF THEM take 2 or more parameters. So clearly you are not showing your real code.

The only way I can see this error happening is if you are calling one of the overloaded versions of `Post()` that has an `ASourceFile` parameter, and you are setting that parameter to an empty string, eg

```
idHTTP.Post(cUrlPath + '/user/logout.json', '')
```

That would cause a `cannot open file ""` exception.